# Get svg from template by tag and put in pdf using pdfmake

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, angular8, pdfmake

I have this html :

```
<ngx-barcode [bc-value]="value" [bc-display-value]="true"></ngx-barcode>
```

I saw that this directive generate the following html :

```
<div class="barcode">
    <svg width="266px" height="142px" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 266 142" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="transform: translate(0,0)">
     ....
    </svg>
</div>
```

Now I want to get the svg tag and put in pdf using pdfmake like an image like this :

```
{
  // if you specify both width and height - svg will be stretched
  svg: '<svg width="300" height="200" viewBox="0 0 300 200">...</svg>',
  width: 600,
  height: 400
},
```

Can you help me please how I can get the `svg` tag from html template in order to be use in pdf definition. Thx in advance and sorry for my english !!! Othe solution is to generate this .svg inside component but I didn't found a solution